# Vue.js loop template

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of projects and I have an array of users.
I would like to make a double loop with :

```
Project  | User | ....
         | U1   | ....
A        | U2   | ....    
         | U3   | .... 
----------------------
         | U1   | ....
B        | U2   | ....    
         | U3   | ....
```

So i use a table element like :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Poject</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th v-for="..." :key="...">....</th>
  </tr>
  <template v-for="p in projects"> // problem :key
    <tr v-for="(u, i) in users" :key="u">
      <td v-if="i===0" :rowspan="users.length">{{p.name}}</td>
      <td>{{u.name}}</td>
      <td v-for="..." :key="...">...</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

I know we cannot loop in a template because its not an element and i need to put the key in an element inside.
An idea is to create a computed with a new array of objects who reflect the structure of my vue like that :

```
[
 { project : "A",
   users : ["U1", "U2", "U3"]
 },
 { project : "B",
   users : ["U1", "U2", "U3"]
 },
]
```

After, i only need to loop inside this new structure.
But if i have a lot of data, i lost a time to recreate this structure.

Do you have a better solution ?

Comment: So why would `v-bind:key` create a problem? Can you post an example of the data you're trying to loop over?

Comment: `But if i have a lot of data, i lost a time to recreate this structure.`
If you worry about performance, then you could make a project-based pagination (load project A, and create "Load more" button below to load another one from your BE). Or just list all your projects with your `v-for` and load it's details only when you click it.

Comment: I'm agree with pagination but this a second step. For data : var project = [ {id:0, name:"A"}, {id:1, name:"B"}] and for users : var user =  [ {id:0, name:"U1"}, {id:1, name:"U2"}, {id:2; name:"U3"}]

Answer (score 0):

I have added two ways to do this. One with css grid, because it seems like a better solution to do this, but perhaps you would like to use the table tag, because some job parses that. (I know that copy pasting to excel works with tables for example)

See this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ll3pml3kjl?fontsize=14

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Users</th>
      </tr>
      <project-row
        v-for="(user, index) in allUsers"
        :user="user"
        :index="index"
        :key="user.name" />
    </table>

    <div class="grid-table">
      <strong class="project">Project</strong>
      <strong class="user">User</strong>
      <template class="projects" v-for="project in projects">
        <span class="project">{{ project.name }}</span>
        <span class="user" v-for="user in project.users">{{ user }}</span>
      </template>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProjectRow from "./components/ProjectRow";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ProjectRow
  },
  computed: {
    allUsers() {
      return this.projects.map(p => {
        return p.users.map((u, i) => {
          return {
            first_in_project_group: i === 0,
            name: u,
            project: p.name,
            total_users: p.users.length
          }
        });
      }).flat();
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      projects: [
        {
          name: "A",
          users: ["UA1","UA2","UA3"]
        },
        {
          name: "B",
          users: ["UB1","UB2","UB3"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.grid-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  max-width: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-self: center; 

  .project {
    grid-column: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .user {
    grid-column: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
</style>
```

**ProjectRow.vue**

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td v-if="user.first_in_project_group" :rowspan="user.total_users">{{ user.project }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      'index': true,
      'user': {
        default() {
          return {
            name: '',
            project: '',
            total_users: 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      users() {
        return this.project.users;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not good because into root template you cannot have a v-for directive